# Get the Blob Using Node Multer Buffer And Convert Blob To Base 64

Tags: node.js, base64, blob, buffer, arraybuffer

I'm trying to get the `Uint8Contents` as Blob to convert to base64 and store it as PgSQL `bytea` coming from the `ArrayBuffer`/`Buffer` using `multer` middleware for Expressjs.

Most of the answers refer to saving it in a file system first, but how would you use the multer memory storage? (I've used it this way)

```js
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'
import multer from 'multer'

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
const api = Router()

api.post('/customer/:customer_id/photo', upload.single('photo'),
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    const customerId = req.params.customer_id
    const photoBuffer = req?.file?.buffer as Buffer

    const arrayBuffer = photoBuffer.buffer.slice(
      photoBuffer.byteOffset,
      photoBuffer.byteOffset + photoBuffer.byteLength
    )

    const uInt8Contents = photoBuffer.readUInt8(photoBuffer.byteOffset)
    console.log("uInt8Contents",uInt8Contents)

    // const arrayBuffer = Uint8Array.from(photoBuffer).buffer
    // const photoBlob = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer).Blob([arrayBuffer])
    console.log("bufferPhoto", arrayBuffer)

    // TODO: Need a code for converting array buffer or buffer to be the correct image Blob

    const base64Photo = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer).toString('base64')
    // Store base 64 photo in PgSQL bytea
    // ...
  }
)
```

I just couldn't figure out how to get the correct Blob to be converted as base64 and store it in PgSQL as `bytea`.

So, the question is: On the second to the last line, how would I convert the file into a `Blob`?

I get this output, but it does not seem to be the `Uint8Contents`of the blob because the image does not display at all.

```
ArrayBuffer {
  [Uint8Contents]: <ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e2 02 a0 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 02 90 6c 63 6d 73 04 30 00 00 6d 6e 74 72 52 47 42 20 58 59 5a 20 07 dd 00 0a 00 08 00 17 00 2b 00 36 61 63 73 70 41 50 50 4c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 2527 more bytes>,
  byteLength: 2627
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing your db? Using sequelize?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the DB, though... because the uploaded file is a `multipart/form-data` and we just need to convert the uploaded binary Blob into base64. To answer your question, we are using an ORM called Objection.

Getting the binary Blob base64 as bytea from the pgSQL DB is already working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue:
https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/464

It was basically a `serverless-offline` issue: When a server is running in `serverless-offline` and the image is uploaded, the binary image gets distorted like this:

[image: Distorted binary image]

Where the binary image should look like this, instead:
[image]

In short, the characters are being changed by `serverless-offline`. The link, however, suggests that if you are going to deploy the code in a `non-serverless-offline` environment, it will work.

So, this code will still work when deployed:

```js
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'
import multer from 'multer'

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const uploadPhoto = multer({ storage: storage }).single('upload')
const api = Router()

v1Api.post('/user/:user_id/photo', uploadPhoto, async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const userId = req.params.user_id
  const photoBuffer = req?.file?.buffer as Buffer
  const binaryPhoto = Buffer.from(photoBuffer).toString('binary')
  const base64Photo = Buffer.from(binaryPhoto).toString('base64')
  console.log(base64photo) // Save this base64photo as bytea
})
```

Otherwise, configure the `serverless.yml` to support binary using this plugin `aws-serverless-express-binary`.

Edit

We deployed it in an environment and it seems to work correctly.